# how to identify specified object using mat through the address provided like 0x3790f200

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm

I used memory analyzer tool to detect memory leak. I got the results like through java.util.WeakHashMap$Entry the class java.lang.Class @ 0x3790f200 System Class ,Native Stack is retaining most heap space. How to identify which object is this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look up that specific object (at address 0x3790f200) click on the magnifier glass icon on the toolbar in the memory analyzer tool and enter the address. Once you see the object right-click on it and select "Show Retained Set". This will open a new histogram table showing all objects (grouped by their type) that are keept in memory by the first object (@0x3790f200). You can select "Calculate Minimum Retained Size" (from toolbar or context menu) which appends a Retained Heap column to the table. Click on the column header to sort the table, so that you can see which objects retain big chunks of memory.

From that point on you can use commands from the context menu like "List objects with outgoing references" to further investigate by looking at individual objects. Also the inspector window is useful to check fields of individual objects.
Hope this helps a bit.